# What does the phrase "I will race you" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does the phrase "I will race you" mean?

Does it mean "let's race" or "I will win you in a race"?

**Edit**: The full sentence is *I will race to the top of the tower*

Comment: More context please.

Comment: "I will win you in a race" does not make sense: the object of "win" is the either the competition ("I will win the race") or the prize ("I will win the first prize in the race"). The common word that fits your frame is "beat": "I will beat you in a race". As to your question: "I will race you" does not mean that I will win, or beat you, only that I am offering to race against you.

Comment: Well, that's a different sentence altogether. What do you think that means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I will race you to the top of the tower" means "let's race". The speaker is challenging someone to get to the top of the tower before him/her. Usually the purpose is either a friendly test of who is the fitter, or as a means of making a choice between them, as an alternative to tossing a coin or negotiating. For example :

> "There's only one bed. One of us will have to sleep on the floor."
>   "I will race you to the top of the tower for it."

Within the limited context you have provided, it is not possible to tell if the speaker is predicting that he/she will win the race. However, within the broader context of a story it is possible that this is what is implied, even if it is not said. For example :

> "There's only one bed. One of us will have to sleep on the floor."
>   "I will race you to the top of the tower for it, Fatty."
>   "I've got a better idea : let's toss a coin."